# Is the error distribution in Learning with Errors (LWE), the discrete Gaussian distribution?

Tags: lattice-crypto, lwe, ring-lwe, gaussian-noise

In $\mathbb{Z}$, the discrete Gaussian distribution is defined as $D_{Z,s}(x) = \frac{\rho_s(x)}{\rho_s(\mathbb{Z})}, x\in \mathbb{Z}$.

In LWE, $(\overrightarrow{a}, b = \langle \overrightarrow{a}, \overrightarrow{s}\rangle + e)\in \mathbb{Z}_p^n\times \mathbb{Z}_p$, the error $e$ is just sampled by rounding from continuous Gaussian, but in [GPV08], the author said that rounding is not the $D_{\mathbb{Z},s}$, their statistical distance is not negligible($\Omega(1/s^3)$).

The error in LWE is not discrete Gaussian? Or what's the relation between the error in LWE and the $D_{Z,s}$?

Comment: Hello. Could you please tell us where you saw that "$e$ is just sampled by rounding from continuous Gaussian"?

Comment: In Seal, for BFV and CKKS, the error term $e(x)= e_0 + e_1x + \cdots + e_{N-1}x^{N-1}$, the coefficients $e_i$'s are just sampled by rounding from continuous Gaussian.

Comment: I'm not sure that whether the LWE and RLWE are different, i.e, the RLWE error could be sampled by rounding, but the LWE could not?

Comment: The answers to this should address your question: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/88685/lwe-round-a-continuous-gaussian-to-a-true-discrete-gaussian